# SQL Oracle LEFT JOIN and SUBQUERY error: ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, left-join, ora-00905

Asking for your help on this Oracle query. It's giving me the error 2 "ORA-00905: missing keyword". It was working fine before I added the LEFT JOIN statement. Obviously it won't deliver the information as we need it without the LEFT JOIN statement.

Please provide any help to know which keyword is missing in this query

Thanks a lot!:

DB Tables:
DW.TICKETS
DW.TICKET_ACTLOG

Subquery table:
TABLE_RESOLVERS

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(DW.TICKETS.RESOLVED_TIMESTAMP,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS RESOLVED_DATE, 
    DW.TICKETS.SUBJECT, DW.TICKETS.OWNER_CORE_ID, 
    DW.TICKETS.TICKET_NUMBER, 
    TABLE_RESOLVERS.SUBMITTER AS RESOLVER_CORE_ID 

FROM DW.TICKETS 

LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        TICKET_NUMBER,
        SUBMITTER 
    FROM DW.TICKET_ACTLOG 
    WHERE 
        TYPE = 'Final Resolution' AND 
        (SUBMITTER = 'B02666' OR 
        SUBMITTER = 'R66604') 
    ORDER BY CREATE_TIMESTAMP DESC 
    ) AS TABLE_RESOLVERS 

ON DW.TICKETS.TICKET_NUMBER = TABLE_RESOLVERS.TICKET_NUMBER  

WHERE 
    DW.TICKETS.RESOLVED_TIMESTAMP >= to_date('05-03-2010','dd-mm-yyyy') AND 
    DW.TICKETS.RESOLVED_TIMESTAMP < to_date('8-03-2010','dd-mm-yyyy') AND 
    DW.TICKETS.TICKET_NUMBER LIKE 'TCK%' AND 
    DW.TICKETS.TICKET_NUMBER IN 
        (SELECT TICKET_NUMBER 
        FROM DW.TICKET_ACTLOG 
        WHERE 
            (SUBMITTER = 'B02666' OR 
            SUBMITTER = 'R66604') 
        ) 

ORDER BY DW.TICKETS.CREATE_TIMESTAMP ASC
```

Comment: Is "TYPE" a reserved word in Oracle?

Comment: @EricPetroelje - TYPE is a keyword but it is not forbidden: it was introduced into the syntax too late for that.

Comment: What version of Oracle is this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Oracle we don't include the `AS` when declaring a table alias.  Instead of

```
    ) AS TABLE_RESOLVERS
```

write

```
   ) TABLE_RESOLVERS
```

This is one example when Oracle syntax is more restrictive than some other flavours of SQL. It is also inconsistent with the declaration of column aliases, which is unfortunate but almost certainly it's too complex to change this far down the road.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the "AS" is extraneous near "AS TABLE_RESOLVERS"

Comment: Just 4 minutes behind haha