# Query Help: Totaling parent / child items

Tags: sql, oracle, view, sql-scripts

[*Ed. Note: Related to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056845/query-help-a-view-that-totals-some-groups); didn't edit question because the problem has fundamentally shifted and question/answers from before are still valid*]

Looking for advice of how best to create a view. The current query from my previous problem now works, but doesn't account for the idea of parent/child items.

## Relevant Data structure

```
+---------+      +---------+
|WORKORDER|      |WPLABOR  |
|---------|      |---------|
|WONUM    |+---->|WONUM    |
|PARENT   |  +   |LABORHRS |
|ISTASK   |  |   |RATE     |
|...      |  |   +---------+
|         |  |
+---------+  |   +---------+
             |   |WPITEM   |
             |   |---------|
             +-->|WONUM    |
             |   |ITEMQTY  |
             |   |UNITCOST |
             |   +---------+
             |
             |   +----------------+
             |   |LONGDESCRIPTION |
             |   |----------------|
             +-->|LDKEY           |
                 |LDTEXT          |
                 +----------------+
```

## Goal

In layman's terms, I am having someone enter a work order number, and pulling a report that has the work order's information, plus a summary of labor and materials cost for all of the child workorders (also called task workorders)

Therefore, I need a view that returns:

- The standard information about that workorder (ID'd by WONUM) -- description, location, etc.
- Total Labor Hours (SUM of LABORHRS) for each of its child task workorders
- Total Labor cost (sum of LABORHRS*RATE) from WPLABOR For each of its child task workorders
- Total Item Cost (SUM of ITEMQTY*UNITCOST) from WPITEM For each of its child task workorders

A **Child Task Workorder** is a workorder where parent = WONUM of first workorder and ISTASK=1

### Use:

I would like to be able to call this in the following way:

```
SELECT * from [ViewName] where wonum = '123abc';
```

I know this involves a combination of subqueries and joins, I'm just not sure what the best way to structure the relationships, etc. is.

## Current Query

```
SELECT WORKORDER.WONUM      ,
       WORKORDER.ACTLABHRS  ,
       WORKORDER.LOCATION   ,
       WORKORDER.STATUS     ,
       WORKORDER.WO7        , -- Requester
       WORKORDER.WO8        , -- Extension
       WORKORDER.WO9        , -- Location
       WORKORDER.LEADCRAFT  ,
       WORKORDER.WO11       , -- Extension
       WORKORDER.GLACCOUNT  ,
       WORKORDER.WO10       , -- Contact
       WORKORDER.DESCRIPTION, -- Short description
       WORKORDER.WO6        , -- Plant rearrangement (YORN / boolean value)
       WORKORDER.ISTASK     ,
       WORKORDER.PARENT     ,
       LABOR.TOTALLABORHRS  ,
       LABOR.LABORCOST      ,
       ITEM.ITEMCOST        ,
       DESCRIPTION.LDTEXT
FROM   MAXIMO.WORKORDER
       LEFT JOIN
              ( SELECT  WPLABOR.WONUM                                    ,
                       SUM(WPLABOR.LABORHRS * WPLABOR.RATE) AS LABORCOST ,
                       SUM(WPLABOR.LABORHRS)                AS TOTALLABORHRS
              FROM     MAXIMO.WPLABOR
              GROUP BY WONUM
              )
              LABOR
       ON     WORKORDER.WONUM = LABOR.WONUM
       LEFT JOIN
              ( SELECT  WPITEM.WONUM ,
                       SUM(WPITEM.ITEMQTY * WPITEM.UNITCOST) AS ITEMCOST
              FROM     MAXIMO.WPITEM
              GROUP BY WONUM
              )
              ITEM
       ON     WORKORDER.WONUM = ITEM.WONUM
       LEFT JOIN
              ( SELECT LONGDESCRIPTION.LDKEY,
                      LONGDESCRIPTION.LDTEXT
              FROM    MAXIMO.LONGDESCRIPTION
              WHERE   LONGDESCRIPTION.LDOWNERTABLE='WORKORDER'
              AND     LONGDESCRIPTION.LDOWNERCOL  = 'DESCRIPTION'
              )
              DESCRIPTION
       ON     WORKORDER.WONUM = CAST(DESCRIPTION.LDKEY AS VARCHAR(22)) HERE WORKORDER.ISTASK = 1;
```

### Issues with Current Query

Because it doesn't take child task workorders into account, it doesn't return any labor or item records (none are directly associated with the parrent), and so the labor and item totals are always empty.

Comment: Connect by prior will traverse the parent child tree for you and grouping sets can sum up the totals.  Will take a fair amount of effort to write up the logic.

Comment: I've never worked with connect by prior. would you be willing to submit an answer where you lay out the logical/pseudo-sql concepts? I think if I saw the basic idea of steps I need to take, I would have a lot more to go off of. Much appreciated!

Comment: The question would be easier to read if correlation names were used, and the mixture of ALLUPPERCASE and CamelCase were avoided. Also: I cannot see how the LONGDESCRIPTION table should relate to any of the other three tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a query that resolves the situation and is a little faster than "connect by prior "method (3 seconds compared to ~90 seconds).

To make it a little easier, I separated the standard Work Order information into a separate view (I'd like to re-use it anyway).

The query I ended up with (below) seems to do the trick:

```
CREATE OR replace VIEW r_wo_costsummariesbyparent 
AS 
  SELECT workorder.parent, 
         Nvl(SUM(wosummary.totallaborhoursforwo), 0) AS totallaborhoursforparent, 
         Nvl(SUM(wosummary.totallaborcostforwo), 0)  AS totallaborcostforparent, 
         Nvl(SUM(wosummary.totalitemcostforwo), 0)   AS totalitemcostforparent 
  FROM   maximo.workorder 
         inner join (SELECT workorder.wonum, 
                            Nvl(SUM(wplabor.laborhrs), 0) AS totallaborhoursforwo, 
                            Nvl(SUM(wplabor.laborhrs * wplabor.rate), 0) AS totallaborcostforwo, 
                            Nvl(SUM(wpitem.itemqty * wpitem.unitcost), 0) AS totalitemcostforwo 
                     FROM   maximo.workorder 
                            inner join maximo.wplabor 
                              ON ( workorder.wonum = wplabor.wonum ) 
                            inner join maximo.wpitem 
                              ON ( workorder.wonum = wpitem.wonum ) 
                     WHERE  workorder.istask = 1 
                     GROUP  BY workorder.wonum) wosummary 
           ON workorder.wonum = wosummary.wonum 
  GROUP  BY workorder.parent;
```

I use it in the following way:

```
Select * from r_wo_costsummariesbyparent where parent = '123abc';
```

Comment: Can a WONUM exist as a primary key without any Childkeys (no records with parent field matching wonum? If so, do you want to see the parents in the result with 0 hours and 0 item costs?  If so, then you inner join on the outer select needs to be a left join.  Second, you're design REQUIRES there to be both a wplabor record AND a wpItem record or you will get no record back. DO ALL your workorders HAVE both wplabor and wpitems and will they continue to do so?  If not then you need to use left joins on the inner select.